# Signing an assembly with Visual Studio and LibZ Container

Tags: c#, wpf, security, .net-assembly, code-signing

I have a relatively simple WPF application that I've created in Visual Studio. Because the application has some dependent DLLs (packages pulled down from Nuget), I've also been using a helper application called [LibZ Container](https://github.com/MiloszKrajewski/LibZ), which is just like ILMerge except it works with WPF applications. (In other words, it combines the EXE and all DLLs into a single EXE file.)

When I upload my EXE file to the web and subsequently download it, I get a warning -- in whatever browser I'm in -- that the file may be unsafe. For example here's Chrome's warning:

[image: MyCoolApplication.exe is not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous.]

[image: Keep file? Even if you have downloaded files from this site before, the site may be temporarily unsafe (hacked). Try downloading this file later. Cancel. Keep anyway.]

My *assumption* is that I see this warning because the file was unsigned. So, I purchased a code-signing certificate from Comodo. It took jumping through a lot of different hoops to finally get the certificate in the correct PFX format, but I eventually did, and was able to use it in the "Sign the assembly" portion of the Build properties for my project, in Visual Studio.

[image: Sign the assembly: Choose a strong name key file.]

That seems to work properly, meaning the project builds successfully and uses the PFX file to do the signing. **However,** if I check on the file by running `signtool verify /pa MyCoolApplication.exe`, the signtool utility reports that the file is unsigned. This is even before I've attempted to merge in the DLLs using LibZ container.

When I do use LibZ Container to do the merge, I use this command:

> libz inject-dll --assembly MyCoolApplication.exe --include *.dll --move

And as always, that works; however, if I check things with signtool, it still reports that the file is unsigned. I then attempt to use LibZ's built-in signing mechanism by running this command:

> libz sign --include MyCoolApplication.exe --key key.pfx --password abc123

However, the console output I get from that ends by saying:

> Assembly '.\MyCoolApplication.exe' is already signed so it does not need resigning

I can post the full output of that command if anyone is curious. But again, signtool.exe reports that the file is unsigned. Are there two different types of signing going on here, that I'm not aware of?

How can I get this executable signed, using my code signing certificate, so that the browser warnings will go away? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the current, allegedly signed exe? `signtool` might be a bit confused.

Comment: I did try that, yes. Unfortunately it did indeed have the same warning as usual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I didn't realize when I posted this question is that simply ticking the box to "Sign the Assembly" is really only the first step, but what's also needed is explicitly calling the `signtool.exe` to sign the executable.

I found [a number](http://www.tech-pro.net/code-signing-for-developers.html) [of guides](https://olepetterdahlmann.com/2016/07/11/code-signing-wpf-application-part-2/) [online](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-2/) all explaining that this is the case. Thanks to those guides, I realized I needed to run these commands:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /f key.pfx /p abc123 /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com /v "MyCoolApplication.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /f key.pfx /p abc123 /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/?td=sha256 /td sha256 /v "MyCoolApplication.exe"
```

I also discovered the usefulness of a third-party library called [StrongNameSigner](https://github.com/brutaldev/StrongNameSigner) in automatically giving strong names to the unsigned third-party libraries I was using.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it seems that this problem (the error message, not the `signtool` issue) is quite common. Unfortunately, it also seems that there is not one commonly-accepted method to resolve it. Numerous articles and forum postings abound recommending remedies with very tenuous empirical backing. That being said, these are the remedies that seem to have the most reasonable support behind them:

1. [Request a review of your site/link from Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/docs/request_review?visit_id=1-636193257658863513-671462546&hl=en&rd=1)
2. [Add a logo to your executable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt637084.aspx)
3. [Make sure your headers are in order](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/lrsSvvmjSPc/psO72k1MBBIJ)
4. Add your site in [Google Webmasters](https://www.google.com/webmasters/#?modal_active=none)
5. Have more people download the file, or just download it yourself multiple times from multiple machines.

Signing your file, which you have attempted to do, is recommended by several posters, but does not seem to have much empirical verification, or any mention by Google.